# Trying to install zgrviewer to view DOT files

Tags: java, bash, graphviz

I am trying to install zgrviewer on my Ubuntu machine,to view DOT files. I have already installed java jdk 1.6 and Graphviz (sudo apt-get install graphviz).

The java installation path i notice after typing "which javac" is /usr/bin/javac.

I checkout the zgrviewer from sourceforge.net:

svn co https://zvtm.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/zvtm/zgrviewer/trunk zgrviewer

I am supposed to launch zgr viewer by running the run.sh script. The contents of the run.sh script is:

```
   #!/bin/sh
   # If you want to be able to run ZGRViewer from any directory,
   # set ZGRV_HOME to the absolute path of ZGRViewer's main directory
   # e.g. ZGRV_HOME=/usr/local/zgrviewer

     ZGRV_HOME=/usr/local/zgrviewer

     java -Xmx1024M -Xms512M -jar $ZGRV_HOME/target/zgrviewer-0.9.0-SNAPSHOT.jar "$@"
```

I am not sure how to edit this script to point to a specific Java Virtual Machine ; right now, it just says java and therefore uses the first JVM it finds in my PATH.

so when i run the script it says: Unable to access jarfile /usr/local/zgrviewer/target/zgrviewer-0.9.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

Please help me install zgrviewer successfully.

Comment: Wouldn't this question fit better on http://superuser.com ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like graphviz a lot, but I eventually gave up on the native "dot" viewers.  Instead, I build (or obtain) graphviz with pdf support, and translate .dot to pdf.  From there, many PDF viewers work well (and they tend to be more polished than dot viewers, probably because the need is more common), even for large documents.  I'm mostly a gnome 2.x person, but I find KDE's okular to be the best PDF viewer I've encountered for large PDF's so far.

Comment: How do you translate .dot to pdf?

Answer (score 1):

If this can help, I've written a guide on how to install a Graphviz viewer (ZGRViewer) and thumbnailer on Ubuntu/Gnome.

It is available at http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/74-ubuntu/287-ubuntu-graphviz-viewer-gnome-thumbnailer

I've been able to use ZGRViewer 0.8.2 without any problem, but no success till date with version 0.9.0.